# how can I make a value to be substitute fixed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I' m new at Python, I've just start learning. I'm supposed to clean this DB and substitute 'ct' with 'connecticut' but if I write this

```py
df_cleaned['cust_state'] = df_cleaned['cust_state'].replace("ct","connecticut", regex=True)
```

it will substitute ALL CT in the DF with 'connecticut'. How can I say "JUST THAT SINGLE ct"?

thank you

```py
array(['new york', 'new jersey', 'pennsylvania', 'ct', 'south carolina',
           'michigan', 'connecticut', 'georgia', 'arizona', 'alabama', 'ohio',
           'florida', 'maryland', 'texas', 'california', 'hawaii', 'oklahoma',
           'new mexico', 'indiana', 'colorado', 'north carolina', 'tennessee',
           'washington', 'oregon', 'louisiana', 'illinois', 'utah', 'vermont',
           'minnesota', 'nevada', 'virginia', 'west virginia', 'idaho',
           'montana', 'wyoming', 'arkansas', 'massachusetts', 'missouri',
           'kansas', 'nebraska', 'wisconsin', 'north dakota', 'mississippi',
           'kentucky', 'district of columbia', 'alaska', 'rhode island',
           'maine', 'delaware', 'south dakota', 'iowa', 'new hampshire'],
          dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add start two anchors, start of line `^` and end of line `$` to you regex:

```
df_cleaned['cust_state'].replace("^ct$", "connecticut", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `loc`:

```
df_cleaned.loc[df_cleaned['cust_state'].eq('ct'), 'cust_state'] = 'connecticut'
```

Which will locate all rows where 'cust_state' equals 'ct', and replace it with 'connecticut'

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers if your issue was resolved. It is the ✔ button next to each answer.